# How to split a column into many columns where the name of this columns change

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I defined a data frame into a "function" where the name of each column in the dataframes changes continuously so I can't specify the name of this column and then split it to many columns. For example, I can't say `df ['name']` and then split it into many columns. The number of columns and rows of this dataframes is not constant. I need to split any column contains more than one item to many components (columns).

For example:

This is one of the dataframes which I have:

```
name/one                                                name/three         

(192.26949,)                                      (435.54,436.65,87.3,5432) 

(189.4033245,)                                (45.51,56.612, 54253.543, 54.321) 

(184.4593252,)                                 (45.58,56.6412,654.876,765.66543)
```

I want to convert it to:

```
name/one                 name/three1      name/three2     name/three3       name/three4 

192.26949                  435.54          436.65            87.3              5432 


189.4033245                45.51           56.612          54253.543          54.321 

184.4593252                45.58           56.6412          654.876          765.66543
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution if all data are tuples in all rows and all columns use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `DataFrame` constructor and [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(df[c].tolist()).add_prefix(c) for c in df.columns], axis=1)
print (df)
    name/one0  name/three0  name/three1  name/three2  name/three3
0  192.269490       435.54     436.6500       87.300   5432.00000
1  189.403324        45.51      56.6120    54253.543     54.32100
2  184.459325        45.58      56.6412      654.876    765.66543
```

If possible string repr of tuples:

```
import ast

L = [pd.DataFrame([ast.literal_eval(y) for y in df[c]]).add_prefix(c) for c in df.columns]
df = pd.concat(L, axis=1)
print (df)
    name/one0  name/three0  name/three1  name/three2  name/three3
0  192.269490       435.54     436.6500       87.300   5432.00000
1  189.403324        45.51      56.6120    54253.543     54.32100
2  184.459325        45.58      56.6412      654.876    765.66543
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I tested the code which you sent, but when i tried to save these dataframes in many sheets for one excel file, there are zeros added to the name of each field such as "Log/Info0000000000". How can I remove these zeros?

Comment: @Elwakdy - Hard question,it seems data related problem. Is possible share some file if not confidental?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mC_3zipPNm76aWMMSQrpeKeAPpgAZcuM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1oj_7JxMderaoUz6O0rDUAb2deg299dbH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I send you a code, you can read the content of this file by this code

Comment: @Elwakdy - Problem is for some reason binary columns names

Comment: Thank you so much, Jezrael. Is there anyway to overcome on this problem?

Comment: Regardless about the name of the fields, there is a problem in splitting last two dataframe. If you look to the last two sheets in the Excel file "sheet_len_22" and "sheet_len_15744". There is a problem in the spiting the columns into many other columns. I can sen you the original Excel file if you wish to make a comparison between the excel sheet you get when you run the code and the original one.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ecpNgGiaDLNTuZmgtV1arO0roWc9R6MD/view?usp=sharing